# Is `without` required only noun?

Tags: prepositions

I met an English sentence like below.

> After testing on multiple machines root configurations, I was able to notice that it happens only using homestead without nfs folder sync.

This sentence includes *without nfs folder sync* and I thought *without* requires noun after it.

But *nfs folder* is a noun and *sync* is a verb, this sentence seems to be wrong.

Is there a case we use a sentence after the word *without*?

Answer (score 0):

In this context, “sync” is a noun, and “nfs folder” is an adjective qualifying that noun. So it’s a perfectly standard use of “without”.

Comment: Nope, *folder* is never an adjective. Neither is NFS. Modification of a noun does not make something an adjective. These are simply nouns used attributively to compose compound nouns.

Comment: @tchrist I see, I got it `compound nouns` as compound nouns.